# jQuery- counting articles in a row- it counts items from both boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count the articles in the top row of the two boxes on the page.
The boxes are separate and I want the count to be like that too -

```
function calculateArticlesInRow() {
var articleInRow = 0;
$('.promotionWrapper').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prev().length);
    if($(this).prev().length > 0) {
        console.log($(this).offset().top + '='+ $(this).prev().offset().top);
        if($(this).offset().top != $(this).prev().offset().top){
            return false;
        }
        articleInRow++;
    }
    else {
        articleInRow++;   
    }
});

    $('.result1').html('No: of articles in a row = ' + articleInRow);
}

setTimeout(function(){
    calculateArticlesInRow();
}, 3000);
```

The problem I'm having however, is that the script is counting the articles in both boxes when only the articles with a certain top offset should be counted.

I have found other questions like this, but the all seem to use only one box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a fiddle so you can see what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/JackofD/de31nojn/

Thanks in advance

Comment: will you show also the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should count the `.promotionWrapper` articles for each `.productWrapper` section.

i've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de31nojn/13/).

```
var articleInRow = 0,
    maxArtNo = 0;
// cycle for every .productWrapper
$('.productWrapper').each(function (index, el) {
    articleInRow = 0
    // cycle for every .promotionWrapper in this .productWrapper
    $('.promotionWrapper', el).each(function (innerIndex, innerEl) {

        //your code 

    });
    //set the count to the max
    if (articleInRow > maxArtNo) maxArtNo = articleInRow;
});
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to work the way that I want. You've been a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. Didnt see the jsfiddle.

Here is a working solution independent of your code:

```
var articlesInRow = [];
$('.productWrapper').each(function (index) {
    articlesInRow[index] = $(this).find('.promotionWrapper').length;
    $('.result' + (index+1)).html('No: of articles in row' + (index + 1) + ' = ' + articlesInRow[index]);
});
```

which i added to your calculateArticlesInRow function.

Please see updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/de31nojn/15/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response(to everyone else also).
Although the article count at the bottom doesn't seem to change on update.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.contentWrapper').each(function(){
    //finds how many articles in the current container
    console.log($(this).find('.promotionWrapper').length);
});
```

But to get each container individually, maybe you should put a separate class on each section tag instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I thought about that, but I wanted to try and get it without giving them invidual classes or ids.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting all the sections with "promotionWrapper" class. To count the 1st row only, you need to select its parent section first and then count children of that. Here is the code:

```
$('.productWrapper:first').children('.promotionWrapper').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).prev().length);
    if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
        console.log($(this).offset().top + '=' + $(this).prev().offset().top);
        if ($(this).offset().top != $(this).prev().offset().top) {
            return false;
        }
        articleInRow++;
    } else {
        articleInRow++;
    }
});
```

Comment: `.productWrapper:first` returns something only if the `.productWrapper` is the first child of its container. maybe change to `$('.productWrapper').first()` ?